# Time to first byte (TTFB) high in Chrome & FF, instant in Safari

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, wordpress, apache2

We have a Wordpress instance running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Apache 2.2.22, and it takes > 3 minutes to load a page in Chrome and Firefox, whereas it loads instantly in Safari.

I have no idea what the issue could be. I tried setting

```
HostnameLookups Off
```

in Apache, in case DNS lookups of client IPs slowed everything down, but that didn't help.

Admins recently upgraded the Wordpress instance, but I have no idea if the issue is related to that.

Comment: The static resources loaded quickly as soon as the main document was there, but in theory you're right, that would have been a good test.

Answer (score 0):

Did a distro upgrade to 14.04.5 LTS. 
This fixed it, the underlying reason for the bug will thus remain a mystery forever.